# How to set text box to appear blank after .click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a simple log in that requires a user to input values from a json file into two different text boxes ,when the user name and (in this case I have used ID as password) matches then an alert appears to say... "welcome"

After the .click function is carried out the users text still remains in the text box, how can I get both text boxes to appear blank after the .click function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Hide alert when page loads
$("#loginalert").hide();
$("#invalid").hide();  
$("#loginbtn").click(function(event){

    $.getJSON('result.json', function(jd) {
        var id = $('#userName').val();
        var name = $('#userName2').val();
        var valid = false;


        for (var i=0; i<jd.user.length; i++) {
            if ((jd.user[i].ID == id) && (jd.user[i].name == name)) {
                valid=true;
                $('#loginalert').html('<img src="' + jd.user[i].imgpath + '"><br><p> Welcome: ' + jd.user[i].name + '</p><button type="button" id="btnhide" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Hide</button>');      
          //show the alert after loading the information  
                $("#loginalert").stop().fadeIn('slow').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 3000)
                $('#invalid').hide();
                $('#btnhide').on('click', function(e){
                    //console.log('here');
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#loginalert').hide();
                });

            }
        }
        if (!valid) {
            $('#invalid').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#loginalert').hide();

        }
    });
}); });
```

## username 1 and #username 2 are the text boxes   - is there any way to get user name 2 to display in stars ****** when the user enters the password -  this question is not that necessary but if i could also get that working that would be good.

thanks guys hope someone can help :)

Comment: As far as blanking the text boxes, wouldn't calling $('#username').val('') do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > is there any way to get user name 2 to display in stars ****** when
   >   the user enters the password

You can use an `input` box with `text` property set as `password`. But that password masking character will be `.` instead of `*`. Not exactly sure, whether it will be a different character in some browsers.

```
<input type="password" id="txtPassword" />
```

2. > text box to appear blank after .click function

You can set the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) property of the jQuery objects of two those two textboxes.

```
$('#userName, #username2').val('');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `<input type="password">` to show typing as stars.

Clear inputs by setting their value to be empty: `$('#userName').val('')`;

And perhaps consider breaking your code down into a couple smaller functions so it's easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("#myTextbox").value="";
```

This should get your textbox and set the value of it to "", which is blank.

Edit: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b77eefvv/5/)

Answer (score 0):

> Using querySelector:

```
<input id="inputId" type="name" />
<button onclick="click()"> Clear </button>
<script>
    function click() {
        document.querySelector('#inputId').value="";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: **getElementbyId** can also be used

Comment: Why even put it in a function?

<button onclick="function () {document.querySelector('#inputId').value='')"> Clear </button>

Should work?

Comment: It wont work, Try it in CodeEditor and see

Comment: To use it Directly inside the Button (onclick), you dont need to write the function name.  See the answer Below

Answer (score 0):

> **Another Method:**

You can also add the script directly **inside the button** without using/creating a **function**.

```
<input id="inputId" type="name" />
<button onclick="document.querySelector('#inputId').value='';"> Clear </button>
```